# Is there a way to category the type of devices in bluetooth scan list and get the Mac address in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

I'm trying to get the devices list from the Bluetooth but not get all the devices (get some of these devices low energy) and not get the Mac address of this devices, there is any way to get all the devices included mobile and hours and headset ....?

```
mgr = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:NULL];
[mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {


}
```

[I need to show list like this image (Mac addresses and type the device)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL2JQ.jpg)
[that's what really show :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQOD.jpg)

Comment: You can only discover BLE peripherals, using Core Bluetooth. Legacy BT peripherals aren't visible to apps. You can't get the MAC address for BLE peripherals using Core Bluetooth.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: For non BLE devices you have to use the External Accessory Framework. It can show you a list of connected devices.